# How to fix: firebase .on method listens two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm making a Discord/Slack clone app with react, redux and firebase...

Adding users to a collection works fine. I have a plus icon which renders a modal to add a new channel. When submitting a function is called to store the newly added channel in my Redux global state and also add it to firebase RealTime Database. (I can see that in firebase console)

It adds correctly to the DB. In my 'Channel' component I have a function which listens to the DB and gives me the values a my snapshot when a channel is added.

The problem is: it gives me the same snapshot twice.

I've tried with the NPM package 'react-firebase-hooks' as well as without them. I always get two snapshots.

I also tried the '.once' method but that doesn't work either.

At first I thought it was a problem with useEffect() and componentDidMount. I Thought that by mistake it would cause a re-render of my channels component, but that's not the case.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';
import { saveLatestChannel } from '../../../actions/channelActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import firebase from '../../../firebase';

const AddChannelModal = ({ saveLatestChannel, user }) => {
  const [channelName, setChannelName] = useState('');
  const [channelDescription, setChannelDescription] = useState('');

  const addChannelToDatabase = () => {
    const channelsRef = firebase.database().ref('channels');
    const key = channelsRef.push().key;

    const newChannel = {
      id: key,
      name: channelName,
      description: channelDescription,
      // createdAt: new Date(),
      createdBy: {
        name: user.user.displayName
        // userID: user.user.uid
      }
    };
    /// CHANNELS GET ADDED HERE
    channelsRef
      .child(key)
      .update(newChannel)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (channelName === '' || channelDescription === '') {
      M.toast({ html: 'Please enter channelname and description' });
    } else {
      addChannelToDatabase();
      saveLatestChannel({
        channelName: channelName,
        channelDescription: channelDescription
      });
      setChannelName('');
      setChannelDescription('');

      M.toast({ html: `Added '${channelName}' as channel` });
    }
  };
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import AddChannelModal from './AddChannelModal';
import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import firebase from '../../../firebase';
import Channel from './Channel';


const Channels = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //init Materialize
    M.AutoInit();
    /// listen for new channels when added to firebase
    newChannelListener();
  }, []);

  const newChannelListener = () => {
    let loadedChannels = [];
    const channelsRef = firebase.database().ref('channels');
    /// PLACING A LISTENER ON CHANNELS HERE IN DB

    channelsRef.on('child_added', snap => {
      loadedChannels.push(snap.val());
      console.log(loadedChannels);
    });
  };
```

In the console.log() I get this:

```
Channels.js:69 
[{…}]
0: {createdBy: {…}, description: "Test Channel one Desc", id: "-LlkL0yqEA-lrPuGI6Ym", name: "Test Channel one"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Channels.js:69 
[{…}]
0: {createdBy: {…}, description: "Test Channel one Desc", id: "-LlkL0yqEA-lrPuGI6Ym", name: "Test Channel one"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `on` to `once` to avoid this behaviour

```
channelsRef.once('child_added', snap => {
   loadedChannels.push(snap.val());
   console.log(loadedChannels);
});
```

Comment: Hi ! i've tried that also (will edit post after this). This doesn't help. It only listens once and logs it twice. So when I add a new channel via the modal. It doesn't log then anymore. When I refresh my page, the newly added channel doesn't appear also.

Comment: Then... are you sure that is creating 2 items in Firebase database?

Comment: in the DB it adding one channel. Not two if you meant that.

Answer (score 0):

On firebase, first time listen function/listener invokes according to its child length. Suppose you have 4 child under channels, first time it will listen for every child. But later if you add another channel, listen function will invoke once, only for 5th channel.

```
const channelsRef = firebase.database().ref('channels');
/// PLACING A LISTENER ON CHANNELS HERE IN DB

channelsRef.on('child_added', snap => {
  loadedChannels.push(snap.val());
  console.log(loadedChannels);
});
```

First time(on load) your `channelsRef.on('child_added', snap => {})` block of code invoke for every child under channels.

Comment: I know, what could I change about that, so that it only invokes when a new channel is added to DB. When I refresh the page it should fetch all the channels I got in one log.